# Find all positive integers $a, b$ such that $ab = a - 5b + 20$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

$$(a+5)(b-1)=ab-a+5b-5=20-5=15.$$

So, both $a + 5$ and $b-1$ divide $15$.

Then, $a + 5$ is one of $15, -15, 3, -3, 5, -5, 1, -1$, so $a$ is one of $10, -20, -2, -8, 0, -10, -4, -6$ and $b – 1$ is one of $15, -15, 3, -3, 5, -5, 1, -1$, so $b = 14, -14, 4, -2, 6, -4, 2, 0$.

Could all possibilities for $a, b$ found by considering $(a+5)(b-1)$ be just random(not in a probability sense) and not connected to $ab = a - 5b + 20$ at all? In other words, could it be that if some of the possible $a, b$ found this way happen to satisfy $ab = a - 5b + 20$, then it's just a coincidence?

Comment: $b$ can be $16$ but it can't be $14$. Probably an absent-minded mistake but pointing it out anyway. I'll delete this comment once you've edited it.

Comment: you seem to have found them all - the two equations you have (the one you were given and the factorised version) are exactly equivalent so all integer solutions to one are integer solutions to the other

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having $$(a+5)(b-1)=15$$
gives you $$(a+5,b-1)=(1,15),(3,5),(5,3),(15,1),(-1,-15),(-3,-5),(-5,-3),(-15,-1),$$
i.e.
$$(a,b)=(-4,16),(-2,6),(0,4),(10,2),(-6,-14),(-8,-4),(-10,-2),(-20,0).$$
Since $a,b$ are positive integers, $(a,b)=(10,2)$ is the only solution.

Comment: Now that you wrote down $(a + b)(b - 1) = 15$ cleanly without all the middle stuff, I see how my question is silly :)

Answer (score 0):

Hint: rewrite your equation into $$a=-5+\frac{15}{b-1}$$

Answer (score 0):

Or write $b = \dfrac{a+20}{a+5} = 1 + \dfrac{15}{a+5}$, thus $a+5 \mid 15$, and $a+5 = 1, 3, 5, 15$ are the possibilities. But since we consider only positive values, we have:$a+5 = 15 \to a = 10 \to b = 1+1 = 2$.

Comment: $-1,-3,-5,-15$ too.

Comment: not fully writing a solution can lead OP to mistakes in the future. You should've added that there. $a+5=1,3,5$ don't work too.

Answer (score 0):

From ab = a -5b +20, we have b(a + 5) = a + 5 + 15.
Therefore a + 5 divides 15 and a must be positive.Hence a = 10.
Then 15b = 15 + 15, and b = 2.   Edwin Gray